# Scroll to the bottom of the page, after the new container is rendered

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

So, to be direct.. I have `2 containers` with `100vh`, but the second container is rendered when you click on a button from the first container. The button click event function has aswell this line: `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);` which is letting me scroll the the bottom.. Now the problem is that on click, i get information from an api, which takes a little time, and since javascript is `asynchronous`, even if i put my scroll function to the bottom of the function, the scroll function executes itself before waiting for information to get loaded and second container to be rendered. Can somebody tell me how can i fix that ?

Edit: 
So here's some additional info.. The second container is displayed depending on a boolean variable.. In the callback function i set that value to true.

Here's how i do it:

```
.then(res => {
    res.forEach(data => {
        ...
    }

    if (Object.keys(res).lenght > 1) {
        this.isTrack = false
        this.displayTracks = true   <!-- Second's container bool variable -->
        window.scrollTo({top: 5000, behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, since javascript is asynchronous, you have to wait for an event to finish. This procedure is generally handled by `callback functions` in javascript. A callback function is a function that is invoked when an `async` call returns. You can scroll down to the very bottom of the page inside your callback function so that you would not need to worry about synchronizing them.

Comment: Yea, i thought about it, but there is one problem if i do that.. As i said i use Vue.js framework. Now, the second container is displayed depending on a boolean variable. When the api is called, that value changes and the second container is displayed. So, i think this impacts that way of doing it.

Comment: Then, you should also wait for second container's rendering event and finally do what you want to do.

Comment: Yea i know that .. but how exactly i wait for the second container's rendering ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to trigger `scrollTo` in the callback of your API request, or use `async/await` to wait for the request to finish and then trigger the scroll.

Triggering it in the callback of your API request, could look something like this:

```
fetch('someUrl')
   .then(() => {
     window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)
   });
```

Comment: The thing changed a little bit, now i added some more information above. How can i wait for the container to be displayed, then the scroll ?